# Run commands only on release

Tags: windows-10, qt5, qmake, release-management

How do I make a piece of commands in my .pro file run only on release? I've tried  this but this runs wrongly on debug mode as well:

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release)
{
    OUTPUTFILE += "$${DESTDIR_WIN}\\$${TARGET}.exe"
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$(QTDIR)\bin\windeployqt --webkit2 --release $${OUTPUTFILE} $$escape_expand(\n\t)
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Keep the brace on the same line, i.e. `CONFIG(release, debug|release) {`

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Post it as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opening brace must be on the same line as the condition, i.e.

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    ...
}
```